# Best way to shrink a Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

So there is a fair amount of documentation on how to scale up a Cassandra, but is there a good resource on how to "unscale" Cassandra and remove nodes from the cluster? Is it as simple as turning off a node, letting the cluster sync up again, and repeating?

The reason is for a site that expects high spikes of traffic, climbing from the daily few thousand hits to hundreds of thousands over a few days. The site will be "ramped up" before hand, starting up multiple instances of the web server, Cassandra, etc. After the torrent of requests subsides, the goal is to turn off the instances that are not longer used, rather than pay for servers that are just sitting around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just shut the nodes down and rebalance cluster, you risk losing some data, that exist only on removed nodes and hasn't replicated yet.

Safe cluster shrink can be easily done with nodetool. At first, run:

```
nodetool drain
```

... on the node removed, to stop accepting writes and flush memtables, then:

```
nodetool decommission
```

To move node's data to other nodes, and then shut the node down, and run on some other node:

```
nodetool removetoken
```

... to remove the node from the cluster completely. The detailed documentation might be found here: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/NodeTool

From my experience, I'd recommend to remove nodes one-by-one, not in batches. It takes more time, but much more safe in case of network outages or hardware failures.

Comment: on the node removed, to stop accepting writes and flush memtables, then:nodetool decommission . In contrary to this line, after starting decommissioing my node is still accepting writes and decommissioing stuck in UL state Please suggest .

Answer (score 2):

When you remove nodes you may have to re-balance the cluster, moving some nodes to a new token. In a planed downscale, you need to:

1 -  minimize the number of moves.

2 - if you have to move a node, minimize the amount of transfered data.

There's an article about cluster balancing that may be helpful:
[Balancing Your Cassandra Cluster](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/balancing-your-cassandra-cluster)

Also, the begining of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GddZ3pXiDys) is about  add node and remove node operations and best strategies to minimize the cluster impact in each of these operations.

Hopefully, these 2 references will give you enough information to plan your downscale.

Answer (score 0):

First, on the node, which will be removed, flush memory (memtable) to SSTables on disk:

-nodetool flush

Second, run command to leave a cluster:
-nodetool decommission

This command will assign ranges that the node was responsible for to other nodes and replicates the data appropriately.

To monitor a process you can use command:
- nodetool netstats

Found an article on how to remove nodes from Cassandra. It was helpful for me [scaling down cassandra](http://dabbledouble.com/2020/04/06/scaling-down-cassandra-cluster/).All actions are described step-by-step there.

Comment: as URLs could be changed/removed, it's recommended to put major steps into the answer.